# Changing Web.Config in Production Environment

Tags: wcf, deployment, web-config

My client insists not to store prone-to-change configuration settings in the Web.Config file for our *webservice* (WCF). His reasoning is that he will have to deploy the application every time he wants to change this or that setting in the configuration file. He, then, told me to store this configuration information in the database because, he says, that way one can change it whenever one needs without re-deploying the whole application, and because it is a more central place if we ever need to have more than one instance of the service running.

Of course I find this argument and reasoning plainly wrong. However, I would like to provide him with clear evidence in that he his mistaken. Can anyone please point me out a source or two I may site to show him that changes in Web.Config are automatically propagated to the runtime and that he doesn't need to do any kind of re-deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight from MSDN on ASP.NET Configuration.

[ASP.NET Configuration Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx)

> ASP.NET detects any changes to the configuration files and then
>   automatically applies those changes to the affected applications,
>   restarting the applications in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx)